# Java fail File mkdirs() in Unit Tests

Tags: java

how can I make this piece of code to return XRXERROR:

```
if (!file.exists()) {
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        return "XRXERROR";
    }
    return "";

} else {
    return "XRXDIREXISTS";
}
```

I use TemporaryFolder to run it in JUnit

Comment: Change permissions of folder to read-only (in java code itself) and try to create a file and revert back the permissions.

Comment: Why do you write "TemporaryFolder" as a classname. Is it some API you're using, or are you saying you're creating a temporary folder to let the unit test work in?